# thread synchronization in windows store apps (windows 8.1)

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-8, synchronization, windows-store-apps

I want to synchronize two threads through AutoResetEvent ... however, resetevents dont exist in windows 8.1 store apps anymore. does anyone know what I should use other than AutoResetEvents? 
my code is something like this:

thread 1:

```
Void Add(float data)
{
    list.add(data);
    updateResetEvent.Set();
}
```

thread 2:

```
void Update()
{
     while(updateResetEvent.WaitOn())
     {
          render();
     }
}
```

Comment: Add the definition of the updateresetevent variable.

Comment: Thank you, i know that but this is not my complete code, this is a simple code about what i want to do with my AutoResetEvent object. My problem was that i couldn't find AutoResetEvent calss and problem solved. I had a mistake, i was trying to use Windows.System.Threading instead of System.Threading in c#, but now i need an equivalent for  AutoResetEvent in c++ store app. I can't find it, do you know what is this?

Answer (score 0):

`AutoResetEvent` *does* exist in Windows 8.1 Store Apps. In fact I was able to create a test application in VS 2013 (preview version) that uses it.

All I did was add the following line:

```
using System.Threading;
```

I was then able to access these synchronization classes:

```
AutoResetEvent
ManualResetEvent
ManualResetEventSlim
Monitor
Mutex
ReaderWriterLockSlim
Semaphore
```

Comment: oh sorry i think i was trying to use Windows.System.Threading instead of System.Threading however do you know is there any equivalent for AutoResetEvent in c++ store app? i cant find System::Threading in c++.  thank you

Comment: @AMinG - I am not familiar with the C++ side of things. I did look at the docs, but could not find any C++ equivalent for AutoResetEvent. You may have to use the Win 32 API calls. See the section "Threads and synchronization" at the following link for those calls:  [Win32 and COM for Windows Store apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br205762.aspx)